# What is the difference between beats and wave packets?

Tags: optics, waves, wavefunction, oscillators

What is the specific difference between beats and wave packets.
According to my book both are the formed by superposition of two waves having slightly different frequencies

Comment: this may help  http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Waves/wpack.html  and for beats  http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Sound/beat.html

Comment: Thank you Anna for helping

Answer (score 1):

Beats result from the interference of two continuous waves of slightly different frequencies.  Wave packets are of limited duration and can be described as a combination of many waves with a continuous distribution of frequencies.

Answer (score 0):

**Wave packets** are the resultant, or effective, wave due to the super positioning of multiple waves overlapping in space. **Beats** >> (edit) see Emilio's response below :D. They are the response we hear when two (or more) waves are superimposed on each other. This produces an audible high/low attenuation of the sound.

For example, guitarists use beats to tune their strings by playing the equivalent note on a neighboring string and listening for the beats. When the frequencies of the two strings are similar the beat frequency, which is the difference between the two, is low and becomes easily noticeable. From there, the musician can adjust the string tension until the beats disappear and the frequencies are matched.

Comment: This is not really correct. There is no real difference, as regards "real" vs "perception based", between wavepackets and beats. Both are instances of wave interference between two superpositions (respectively of a continuous set and a pair of frequencies) producing both constructive and destructive interference. At the times of destructive interference (i.e. in the nodes between the beats, or at the times before the wavepacket arrives), we don't perceive anything, because the intensity is physically zero.

Comment: Correct, thanks for the clarity Emilio. This is what I meant, but used the wrong words. I like your addition much better, thanks!